# How to override discovery search results

Tags: xslt-1.0, dspace

One of the requirements of the repository I'm working on is to have an `Advanced Search` option from the user interface. Since as of DSpace 4, the Discovery faceted/filtered search & browse is enabled by default as mentioned [here](http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/Advanced-Search-tp4676641p4676669.html), I just put a link in the navigation to point that `Advanced Search` link to `http://myrepository.org/discover`. Now my goal is to suppress the search results whenever the user clicked the `Advanced Search` link.

How can I override the search results such that if there's no query string (eg if the user goes directly to `/discover` page and no facets were selected), it will only show like in the picture below without the search results and the `Now showing items ...` and the pagination divs.

I am using **DSpace version 5.3 Mirage 2 Theme**

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
<xsl:template match="dri:list[@id='aspect.discovery.SimpleSearch.list.search-results-repository']">
    <xsl:variable name="query-string" select="/dri:document/dri:meta/dri:pageMeta/dri:metadata[@element='request'][@qualifier='queryString']"/>
    <xsl:if test="$query-string!=''">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The code above always suppressed the search results whether I have query strings or not.

**EDIT**

I have a problem with the template match that I used in my answer. The styling of the sort options was removed.

[image]

Can someone help me improve my code such that it will not remove the styling of the sort options? The default sort options should look like this:

[image]

I wonder why using that template match removed the styling of the sort options. If I use `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, or `<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>` instead of `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`, it is not returning the result I want to achieve.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After many tries of `template match`, I finally achieved what I want to display. This is the `template match` that I am using to achieve my goal.

```
<xsl:template match="dri:div[@id='aspect.discovery.SimpleSearch.div.search-results']">
    <xsl:if test="contains(@pageURLMask,'query') or contains(@pageURLMask,'filter')">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't know and not sure if this is fool proof. I've tested this when going directly to `/discover` page, no search results displayed and I also tried clicking the search button without entering any values in the search form.

There is a slight problem with this answer. Please see my updated post above.

This is the code that resolved my problems regarding the styling of the sort options.

```
<xsl:template match="dri:div[@id='aspect.discovery.SimpleSearch.div.search-results']">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(@pageURLMask,'query') or contains(@pageURLMask,'filter')">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="dri:div[@id='aspect.discovery.SimpleSearch.div.masked-page-control']/node()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="no-search-results"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="no-search-results" match="dri:div[@id='aspect.discovery.SimpleSearch.div.masked-page-control']"/>
```